# Unix: How to merge many compressed (.gz) files together and exclude header for files nr. 2 etc

Tags: unix, merge, gzip

I have 20 .gz files I want to merge together (but still keep the originals). They all have the same variables in the same order and all have headers. I want to merge them into one .gz file and include only header for the first file. These files are very "big" and therefore I can´t use R to merge them as it would take too much time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at section "Advanced Usage" of the manual page for `gzip`. I'm not sure you can easily do what you want without decompressing the originals and recompressing them in the same destination file.